# How to relate spring-security authentication rules to dataBase users

Tags: spring, spring-security

i read about spring security from spring in action ,and i want to implements this : i have a web application in which there's two kind of users stored in database :

1)Administrator

2)Clients

This is the spring-security.xml :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="name" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

 </beans:beans>
```

So how to relate  :

`<user-service>
     <user name="name" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </user-service>`
To the database user entries(administrator and clients) ?
I added this section to web.xml :

```
 <!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot map like this.

You need to use a custom [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) for this purpose. Using the userDetailsService you can load the user from database and pass it to the spring security framework.

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        User user = getUser(userName); //Load user from database
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found: " + userName);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

security.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```